# grub error no such partition

Tags: windows, grub

Ситуация такая: linux я удалял еще пол года назад, почистил все диски, установил windows10, восстановил загрузчик и все работало. Прошло пол года и вдруг при очередном включении вижу `grub error no such partition`, иду в гугл,  нахожу несколько решений, вспоминаю что делал такое пол года назад. Делаю загрузочную флешку с тем же windows10, загружаюсь, shift+F10, выполняю 
команды

```
bootrec /fixmbr 
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

но ошибка не пропадает. Гуглю дальше - если такой метод не работает то значит не активирован нужный раздел. Окей, сделал загрузочную флешку с `MiniTool Partition Wizard`, загружаюсь, выбираю раздел с ОС, но он уже "Активирован".

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему. На дисках важные фото, которые нельзя потерять. Если установить еще 1 винду, то я так понимаю это не поможет починить загрузчик? И вообще, что могло быть причиной поломки если проблемы с удалением Linux я решил еще давно?

На фото можно увидеть все что показывает `MiniTool Partition Wizard`[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может в UEFI остался мусор?

Comment: @don Rumata, не знаю, а как проверить? если остался то что делать? Там по идее у меня не UEFI а старенький BIOS.

Comment: Ну собсно efi - это штука внутри матери. Вернее та часть, которая интересует. Гугли модель матери и приставку `uefi`/`efi`.

Comment: @don Rumata, а если я установлю еще 1 винду на диск2 например, он у меня почти пустой. У меня починится загрузчик? Мне главное чтобы не удалились фотки и я мог пользоваться компом. Могу потом просто скинуть фотки в безопасное место и форматнуть старую винду. Это поможет? Точнее не так. Новая винда починит загрузчик?

Comment: Тогда качни https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/bionic/release/xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso, через него скинь всё что надо на внешний\другой винт, потом через `gparted live` снеси все разделы, создай руками системный и потом уже ставь туда винду.